# php - preg_match: minimum char count ignored

Tags: php, regex

This is my regex test

```
if (preg_match("/^[a-z0-9\.]{5,25}$/", $reg_username) === false) {
            echo "Testing failed <BR>";
}
```

If `$reg_username` is `real`, the test pass, but I've specified that I need a minimum of 5 chars. **What am I doing wrong?**

I tested the regexp on a online tester and it fails in this case.

Comment: The regex in correct. https://regex101.com/r/qH1uG3/10

Comment: **Small note:** there's no need to escape the dot in a character class. It will lose its regex meaning. You could simplify it as follows: `^[a-z0-9.]{5,25}$`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just failed on reading manual.

`false` will be returned on error, but if string doesn't match you'll receive `0`.

[Check it out carefully](http://php.net/preg_match)

Comment: Yes, yes, yes,yes, I totally agree. My fault was not read carefully the doc.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!(preg_match("/^[a-z0-9\.]{5,25}$/", $reg_username))) {
            echo "Testing failed <BR>";
}
```

Comment: I choosed the other user's answer because he motivated the reply